# Why buttons are not recognized? "can not be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: android

[image: a1]

and this:

[image: a2]

for some reason the buttons are not recognized when I do "findView by id"
ignore "android:text = "-" - this is just a warning...not error

Answer (score 2):

Because you are referencing wrong R.java file in your import , check that you are importing your package R file .

Comment: @ERJAN : because if you've imported android.R class it looks up in android resource mapping class not your recources id's.by importing your package R.java file it represents your resources ids except android resources.

Answer (score 0):

The android.R you imported is the wrong one but Eclipse suggests to auto import this sometimes as if your project's R file hasn't been generated due to an XML error or something, your code will be referencing a file that doesn't exist. 
By importing android.R, eclipse makes sure your code references a class that exists. However, android.R is unlikely to have the same resources you did, and this will raise another set of errors.